# How to create individual chunks when using #+ with spin function in knitr R package

Tags: r

When using #+ with spin I cannot get separate chunks.

For example if my R script is like the one below:

#+

data(cars)

#+

cars

#+

plot(cars$speed, cars$dist)

I get:

````
```{r }
data(cars)

```{r }
cars

```{r }
plot(cars$speed, cars$dist)
```
````

but those are not separate chunks, all the commands are embedded in the same chunk. How can I get separate chunks with spin?

Comment: what version of `knitr` are you using? I'm not seeing that behavior - http://rpubs.com/hrbrmstr/spintest01 (use the code popup to d/l the source)

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you.  Yes, but in the rmarkdown document the chunks do not look separate.  I am using R 3.3.1, knitr 1.14 and rmarkdown 1.0.  However, when I use #' data(cars) #" cars, the chunks in the Rmd document appear separate.

Comment: they look separate in the rpubs example i provided unless i'm going blind

Comment: Thank you @hrbrmstr.  But do they appear separate in your .Rmd file?

Comment: you can d/l the source from that page